# Start foreground multiple times?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, for-loop

I know that multiple calls to `startService(intent)` result in only one started servie and instance, but I was wondering if the same was for `startForeground(int, id, notification)` Here's what the docs say about start service being called multiple times:

> Note that multiple calls to Context.startService() do not nest (though they do result in multiple corresponding calls to onStartCommand()), so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped once
>   Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called...

Because my `onStartCommand()` may be called multiple times, is it okay to have my `startForeground(int, id, notification)` called multiple times? What if I called it 500 times in a for loop, would there still only be one instance?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: yes. BTW why don't you try it?

Comment: @Gavriel How will I know how many instances have came?

Comment: you count them :) Make a static integer in your class or in your Application. If you don't get the correct answer make sure your app doesn't get killed in the middle